# Can an azimuthally symmetric perturbation lift the 2l+1 degeneracy of angular momentum eigenstates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, perturbation-theory

Assume the initial Hamiltonian of a spinless, non relativistic particle is
$$H_0(r,\theta,\phi)=\frac{{\bf p}^2}{2m}+V_0(r)$$
Such that the eigenstates are angular momentum eigenstates $|n,l,m>$, and the energy spectrum is $(2l+1)$-fold degenerate.

Then, we have a perturbation potential of the form 
$$ V(r,\theta,\phi)=f(r)Y_k^0(\theta,\phi) $$
Where $f(r)$ is a function of $r$, and $Y_k^0$ is an spherical harmonic with $m=0$, therefore the potential is azimuthally symmetric.

Can this perturbation lift the degeneracy for all $m$ values?

---

I am inclined to say that due to the azimuthal symmetry of the perturbation, the energy of states with same $n$, $l$ and $|m|$ values could remain degenerate, but I do not know if this is correct. If it is so, I would like to know how to prove it.

Comment: This is what Stark splitting does.

Comment: Yes, I can see how that is true in the particular case of $k=1$. However, if $k$ is an even number I think the energy splitting of states with same $n$ and $l$, and same absolute value of $m$ is the same. I would like to find a simple way to prove or generalize this idea to all values of $k$.